# Issues sending search results from SQLAlchemy/Flask into Jinja Template

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a web app to search through a personal SQLite database containing my watched movies, shows, books, games, etc. I'm testing it out by making a search function. I want to combine three queries into one set of results, and then iterate through those results on my Jinja template to display them. The search queries are done with flask/sqlalchemy as written below:

```
if(request.method=="POST" and len(request.form["searchBar"]) > 0):
        searchVal = request.form["searchBar"]
        startSearch = "%{}"
        genSearch = "%{}%"

        query1 = Media.query.filter_by(title=searchVal)
        query2 = Media.query.filter(Media.title.like(startSearch.format(searchVal)))
        query3 = Media.query.filter(Media.title.like(genSearch.format(searchVal)))

        searchQuery = query1.union(query2, query3).all()
        session["results"] = searchQuery

        return redirect(url_for("results"))
```

The intended behavior is that it redirects to "results" which uses `session["results"]` to pass the data onto my jinja template. However, before it even gets to the results function, for whatever reason I'm getting a 500 response to my POST request. There's a lot of output in the console when I run it, but the recurring message seems to be `TypeError: Object of type Media is not JSON serializable`

Why is this happening? I thought when I do `.all()` it gives me a list I can iterate through. In any case, where am I trying to make it JSON serializable in the first place?

Thank you for the help

Edit: Here is the definition of the Media class

```
class Media(db.Model):
    mediaid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer)
    status = db.Column(db.Text)
    mediatype = db.Column(db.Text)
    seriesid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('series.seriesid'))
    externalinfo = db.Column(db.Text)
    extranotes = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Comment: seems that the error happened on line `session["results"] = searchQuery`. The `Media` class might have custom attributes or methods that are not recognized by the encoder. As a suggestion, try to convert `searchQuery` to a dictionary.

Comment: @RAI I'm not quite sure how I'd convert it to a dictionary. I added statements to print the results of the query in the console before it tries to do the `session["results"] = searchQuery` line, and it displayed the correct results as expected. So I still don't quite get the issue. I'll paste my definition of the Media class if that helps (in an edit to the post)

Comment: `db.Column` could be causing this issue. As an example try to create a function in `Media` class for the testing purpose that will return a dictionary. `def to_dict(self):
    return {
        'mediaid': self.mediaid,
        'title': self.title,
        'year': self.year,
        'status': self.status,
        'mediatype': self.mediatype,
        'seriesid': self.seriesid,
        'externalinfo': self.externalinfo,
        'extranotes': self.extranotes
    }` and use it with `searchQuery = [media.to_dict() for media in query1.union(query2, query3).all()]`

Comment: @RAI that worked! Just to make sure I understand why, the query union .all() function returns a list of media objects, and for whatever reason JSON can't serialize those. So by converting it into a dictionary, it allows me to pass the data on in a readable form?

Comment: serializer transforms the whole object but `db.Column` is an instance of `SQLAlchemy` class which is not serializable due to complex structures and methods.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Flask stores sessions in cookies in the client web browser

This is good for simple tasks

However, it doesn't work well when you need to serialize even slightly complicated things (like Dates or Decimals)

I'd recommend installing and using Flask-Session, in order to use server-side sessions, which can handle serializing things better:

`pip install flask-session`

in app.py:

```
...
from flask_session import Session
...

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "s3cr3t"
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"

Session(app)
```

Then it should work